# why dektrium does not work?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

I have installed new yii2. Installed dektrium/yii2-rbac. Updated my database schema by migration. I don't have authManager component configured. My configuration file:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'asdasd123456qwerty',
    ],
    ...
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    ...
    'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db-local.php'),
    'urlManager' => [...],
],
'params' => $params,
'modules' => [
    'rbac' => 'dektrium\rbac\RbacWebModule',
],
```

When I try get localhost/basic/web/rbac (default admin/admin), I get 403 Forbidden. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

```
'modules' => [
    'rbac' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\rbac\RbacWebModule',
        'admins' => ['admin'],
    ]
],
```

Here is an answer!

Comment: Albeit it is worth to mention, that admins field should contain name of users you have at your disposal for example 'philipp.klemeshov' and it should be applied at tier where you want to use it, common, frontend, backend

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure `authManager` in your configuration file

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\rbac\components\DbManager',
    ],
    ...
],
...
```